# Visual Studio Team Services with GitHub

Tags: git, github, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm looking to setup a CI workflow for my inhouse (closed source ) project. I'm currently using GitHub for git/issue tracking. My application is a desktop application ( no cloud / server deployments ). Therefore workflow should be

- Commit to master on github
- Notify CI via [github webhooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/)
- Run MSBuild
- Run Tests
- Build Release

I like the idea of a hosted CI system but I can't figure out if Visual Studio Team Services requires total commitment or I can just use it for CI and notify it of checkins from Github via normal github hooks. I'm not so interested in migrating issue tracking and git hosting to VS Team Services.

My specific question. Are there hook mechanisms within Visual Studio Team Services for pulling from remote git repo's when [github webhooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/) are received?

Comment: just an idea: could you mirror the github project on VS Online? (not sure how to to that with github, but with plain git you just add a post-receive hook which pushes to the mirror) If that works, you can use VS Online as usual, use it's own hooks and whatnot, without ever really touching the repository directly.

Answer (score 12):

[Automated builds with a GitHub repo](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository) is available in the new version of our build system in Visual Studio Team Services.  We were able to preview it in [Brian Harry's latest keynote](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2014/015) on November 12, 2015.  It's the very last demo.  Hope that will work out for you!

[image: GitHub Repo with Visual Studio Team Services Build System]

You can also [import a GitHub repo into a Git repo in Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/articles/news/2016/sep-21-team-services#import-repository).

[image: Import a GitHub Repo into VSTS]
[image: Import a GitHub Repo into VSTS]

Comment: Did anything ever happen with this?

Comment: @synth3tk - yes, Visual Studio Team Services has integration with GitHub for automated builds.  You can try it out now.