# Visual Studio Team Services with on-premises machines

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am setting up a CI with visual studio team services for a desktop production, and the workflow is as below:

1. Check in code in github which is repository imported in visual studio team services
2. MSbuild from build agent --> build agent is using on-premises machine1
3. Deploy production code to test agent --> test agent is using on-premises machine2
4. Run functional test from test agent --> test agent is using on-premises machine2

Step 1 and 2 is done (thanks to [Visual Studio Team Services with GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211360/visual-studio-team-services-with-github)) but no idea about step 3/4. In TFS2015 the machine2 is domain-joined so that TFS can see it (added in machine group) and then do "Windows Machine File Copy" and "Run Functional Test".
While for team services, how to make team services see this machine2 so that team services can run test and collect reports from the machine2.

Comment: Just found the on-premises test agent can be done via this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/other-servers/net-to-workgroup-vm. Make sure your build/deploy agent can access the test machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [setup an on premise build agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows) and using it to build (You have already done). For this way, the tasks are running on your build agent, so you need to make sure the test agent machine can be accessed from your build agent machine. The test agent machine doesn’t need to be accessible form Team Service.

Comment: @MichaelZhang Since it works for you, you can mark it as answer.